# Rails sharing controller functionality and menus

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Sorry if this seems daft (not much sleep lately) but I'm trying to figure out the best way to share controller (and method) functionality between controllers without writing the same code for each one.

Let's say I have various controllers with the same method called `search`. Inside this method I have situations for the same term for different controllers, like:

```
    case term
      when "beginning_parens"
       @books = Book.where("title REGEXP ? AND localeLanguage LIKE ?", '^\\([0-9]*\\)', params[:language]).not_locked.reorder(order).paginate(:page => params[:page])
      when 'search_all_caps'
       @books = Book.detect_uppercase.not_locked.reorder(order).where("localeLanguage LIKE ?", params[:language]).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Now I don't want to have to write all of that for each controller. And I'd like not to have to pass the `params[:language]`, `paginate`, etc. to each of the cases since I want each one to search by language and paginate as well.

Or course, the instance variable would change among controllers, instead of `@books` we would have `@dvds`, `@games`, etc.

I also find myself having to pass all the `params` in the menu links:

```
= link_to 'with all CAPS', books_search_path(:term => 'search_all_caps', :language => params[:language])
```

And I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this.

I'm already sharing common methods for the models with a file I call at the top of each model with `extend ModelFunctions`. This file contains methods such as `detect_uppercase` which is used above and is common for many controllers. So at least I have that part working :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be writing a bunch of controllers that do just about the same thing, it seems like inheritance might be the way to go here.

Make one controller (let's call it the `BaseController`) and give it all the methods you want the other controllers to have. Then each of your other controllers can inherit from `BaseController` and just override the methods you need them to and set class variables for things like which model to search, what instance variable to set, and so on. For example:

```
  class BaseController < ActionController::Base
    def search
      @@model.where("title REGEXP ? AND localelanguage ...")
    end
  end

  class BooksController < BaseController
    @@model = Book
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't putting all this into the application_controller.rb have the same effect?

Comment: tried it with appliction_controller.rb and I get the following error `uninitialized class variable @@model in ApplicationController`

Comment: Which makes sense, if BooksController inherits from ApplicationController (or BaseController), how can it set a variable used by the parent?

Comment: My mistake - you'll need to set the variable in the parent controller as well, and then just override it in your child classes. Here's a demonstration: http://pastie.org/4266821